# How to fix 'thrown exception caught locally' when using instanceof to determine internal errors type

Tags: javascript, typescript, exception, language-agnostic, jetbrains-ide

I have a block of code that loads a set of plugins. For each plugin, a list of functions is called inside of a try catch block to determine if the plugin has failed or not and act accordingly. At the same time, one of the multiple functions of the plugin can return a specific error that mean that the plugin has not failed but is not valid to execute the next functions with the data.

Let's see an example (the code is Typescript, but I am going to make it as language agnostic as possible):

```
for each plugin:
  try: 
    plugin.function1(data)
    plugin.function2(data)
    plugin.function3(data)

    try:
      plugin.function4(data)
    catch error:
      if error instanceof PluginNotValidForThisKindOfDataError:
        continue
      else:
        throw error
   
    plugin.function5(data)
    plugin.function6(data)
  catch error:
    log(plugin has failed)
```

*(I hope the code is clear enough. I'll update it if required)*

As can be seen, I execute `function4` and I parse the possible errors because one of them (there are multiple) is "tolerable" and just means that it is not valid for `function5` and `function6` with that specific set of `data`. However, I still have to throw the other errors because they are not good. At the end, I catch the global set of errors to determine if the plugin has crashed or not.

What I get in my IDE, JetBrains (WebStorm specifically) is a `thrown exception caught locally` warning. But I am not able to reimagine how to redo that block to act differently. I am not using throws as flow control but just passing the error.

I admit that the main problem is that in Javascript I can not do `catch PluginNotValidForThisKindOfDataError`, which would be the optimal situation (hope its added some day). But, with the tools I have, how can I refactor this?

Thank you very much.

*Added to both `language-agnostic` and `javascript` because of the specific Javascript try-catch method*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three options:

1. Ideally, the plugin wouldn't throw an error for a non-error condition like that. Instead, have it *return* a value that tells the code in your question whether it should run functions 5 and 6.

   If you want to keep it the way it is, though, you can either:
2. Ignore the warning (and probably there's a way to disable it for one line), or
3. Don't re-throw; instead, do the same thing you're doing in the outer `catch` (`log(plugin has failed)`) followed by `continue`. Provided that's just a single function call or similar, the duplication isn't ideal, but isn't horrible either. If there's any complexity to that step, isolate it into a function (perhaps even a local function) and call that from both places.

Comment: Both 1 and 3 are quite hard to implement as the example is oversimplified, I have no full control over plugins and the second catch is actually not a log but another pair of instanceof/throw (Again, I hate JS error handling). However, I'm going to try to adapt the plugins to return an error code, as, as you said, it's the best approach.

Comment: My final approach has been to create a new function that contains everything from the second `try`to the end of the `function6`. Turning the throw into a function may have been useful if the case I actually logged, but this is not the situation. In any case, as the three approaches to take were perfectly explained by you, I marked your answer as correct.